# Function return value different from expected

Tags: c

I having trouble understanding what is happening. The value of second token is some random number instead of 1. Why does the value of second token not the value in the function?

```
struct player
{
char name[20];
enum cell token;
unsigned score;
};


BOOLEAN init_player2(struct player *second, enum cell token)
{
    token = 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct player second;
    init_player2(&second, second.token);
    printf("The value of second token is: %d\n", second.token);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `token = 1;` has no effect on `second.token`. You want `second->token = 1;` (the second argument is redundant).

Comment: Also, I don't see any need to pass the second parameter!

Comment: There must be dozens of almost-dupes for this one, @CBegin you should start out by **searching** SO for comparable questions before asking one yourself.

Answer (score 4):

C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing.

In your code, `second.token` is passed by value, so any change made to it inside the function will not reflect to the caller.

What you're expecting, is the below code

```
void change( int x)
{
      x = 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    int p = 5;
    change(p);
    printf("%d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

to print 10, which is simply not possible. (If you make the call as `change(15);`, *imagine the horror*.)

Solution:

You don't need to pass the second argument separately. You're already passing the pointer to the structure containing the enum variable, just use the pointer to change the value in the called function, and then in the caller, print the value of the enum member of the structure variable.

Comment: As the accepted answer of the dup states: C does never do pass-by-reference. It is strictly pass-by-value. Regarding the constant: Python is strictly pass-by-reference, but still you can pass a literal to a function. And it works like a charm. No horror!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct player
{
char name[20];
enum cell token;
unsigned score;
};


BOOLEAN init_player2(struct player *second, enum cell token)
{
    second->token= 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct player second;
    init_player2(&second, second.token);
    printf("The value of second token is: %d\n", second.token);

    return 0;
}
```

You just need to use variable of structure inside function using pointer to change the value.

Comment: What is the use of passing the second argument?